# How to call out a specific dictionary using the username in nested dictionary that was formed from a text file in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, variables, nested

**I have successfully created a nested dictionary from a text file but now I want to call out a specific dict out of the nested ones with a variable**

```
#Text file
    
    shanm = null|Shanmugaraja|09/04/2002|0149606345|020409140817|0199999999|4870 2929 0108 2870
    jiken = null|Soo Idiot Jiken|08/06/2000|0199999999|020908140213|011349780|8900 2828 1129 0889
    keller = null|Mathew Keller|02/05/2002|0199999999|0203140819|019607892|9801 2828 5596 0889
```

#This is my code for the nested dictionary

```
    keys = ["Full Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number",
            "Identification Card (IC) Number", "Emergency Contact Number",
            "Credit /Debit Card Details "]
   username = "jiken"
    
    with open("something.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            key, values = line.strip().split(" = ") # note the space around =, to avoid trailing space in key
            values = values.split('|')
            # print(key)
            data2 = {key: dict(zip(keys, values[1:]))}
            print(data2)
```

#output. It is working but I don't want to call out the entire dict instead I just want to call out the dict that starts with the name "jiken" but it's not working

```
    {'shanm': {'Full Name': 'Shanmugaraja', 'Date of Birth': '09/04/2002', 'Phone Number': '0149606345', 'Identification Card (IC) Number': '020409140817', 'Emergency Contact Number': '0199999999', 'Credit /Debit Card Details ': '4870 2929 0108 2870'}}
    {'jiken': {'Full Name': 'Soo Idiot Jiken', 'Date of Birth': '08/06/2000', 'Phone Number': '0199999999', 'Identification Card (IC) Number': '020908140213', 'Emergency Contact Number': '011349780', 'Credit /Debit Card Details ': '8900 2828 1129 0889'}}
    {'keller': {'Full Name': 'Mathew Keller', 'Date of Birth': '02/05/2002', 'Phone Number': '0199999999', 'Identification Card (IC) Number': '0203140819', 'Emergency Contact Number': '019607892', 'Credit /Debit Card Details ': '9801 2828 5596 0889'}}
```

#Desired output, I want it to just print the dict according to the username variable in this case, **"jiken"**

```
    {'jiken': {'Full Name': 'Soo Idiot Jiken', 'Date of Birth': '08/06/2000', 'Phone Number': '0199999999', 'Identification Card (IC) Number': '020908140213', 'Emergency Contact Number': '011349780', 'Credit /Debit Card Details ': '8900 2828 1129 0889'}}
```

Comment: I showed you how to do this in the question you posted earlier. Why are you asking again?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `key == username` and then create data2 out of it as below:

```
keys = ["Full Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number",
            "Identification Card (IC) Number", "Emergency Contact Number",
            "Credit /Debit Card Details "]
username = "jiken"
    
with open("something.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, values = line.strip().split(" = ") # note the space around =, to avoid trailing space in key
        values = values.split('|')
        # print(key)
        if key == username:
            data2 = {key: dict(zip(keys, values[1:]))}
            print(data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
keys = ["Full Name", "Date of Birth", "Phone Number", "Identification Card (IC) Number", "Emergency Contact Number", "Credit /Debit Card Details "]


data2 = {}
    
with open("something.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, values = line.strip().split(" = ") # note the space around =, to avoid trailing space in key
        values = values.split('|')
        data2[key] = dict(zip(keys, values[1:]))
        
# Here, you can add any username and take respective data.
username = "jiken"      
print(data2[username])

username = "shanm"
print(data2[username])
```